# Try to export as json, blender throws this error: AttributeErrpr: 'Image' object has no attribute 'file_path_from_user'

Tags: python, texturing, three.js

[image]Hey guys, 
I recently started working with blender for a game which will be programmed in three.js. Therefore I export my model as a json file. As I load textures from png files in it, blender throws an error pictured in the photo.
Thanks for every advice!

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your version of blender. The `image.filepath_from_user()` was added to blender in 2.70 and you are using 2.69

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/585266/183698) appears to include an up to date source for blender.

If you are using [steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/365670/) you can also install blender from there.